# Creating New Form Controls in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have a button, when clicked, creates a new picturebox control. So that everytime I click it, it adds another new picturebox control. These pictureboxes will all have the same functions like being able to move them around and draw on them. But the button only makes one and no more after that with the following code. What am I missing?

```
 Public Class Form1
        Dim xpos As New Integer
        Dim ypos As New Integer
        Dim pos As New Point
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim canvas As New PictureBox
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Dim i As Integer = 0
            i = i + 1
            canvas.Name = "canvas" & i
            canvas.BackColor = Color.White
            canvas.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            canvas.Image = Nothing
            canvas.Height = TextBox1.Text
            canvas.Width = TextBox2.Text
            AddHandler canvas.MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox1_MouseDown
            AddHandler canvas.MouseMove, AddressOf PictureBox1_MouseMove
            Controls.Add(canvas)

        End Sub
        Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
            xpos = Cursor.Position.X - canvas.Location.X
            ypos = Cursor.Position.Y - canvas.Location.Y
        End Sub

        Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                pos = MousePosition
                pos.X = pos.X - xpos
                pos.Y = pos.Y - ypos
                canvas.Location = pos
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Try and put `Dim canvas As New PictureBox` inside the button handler, so that everytime the program will create a new varible. At the moment, you create only one - when the form is loaded.

Comment: i tried that. the picturebox mouse event handlers dont recognize canvas then.

Comment: `Dim i As Integer = 0  i = i + 1` This wil always be 1 so your name will always be the same. Together with Eminem's suggestiong this should solve your problem. To access canvas in mousemove use `DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Location = pos`

Comment: Because you create the `i` variable in button_click, which means it is local to the function. Every time you click it gets re-created. If you make it private it will do what you wanted to do.

Comment: so i should dim the i up above in the public?

Comment: Indeed, I added a small sample to clarify below

Answer (score 1):

```
   Dim canvas As New PictureBox
```

You have multiple bugs in your code but this is the most serious one.  The `As New` syntax ensures that you'll always create a PictureBox object, but it will only ever be **one** object.  And of course, one variable cannot keep track of multiple picture boxes.

What you need to do is create a new one ever time the button is clicked.  It is generally a good idea to keep track of the picture boxes you create.  So correct code looks like:

```
   Dim canvases As New List(Of PictureBox)

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim canvas = New PictureBox
       canvases.Add(canvas)
       canvas.Name = "canvas" & canvases.Count.ToString()
       '' etc...
   End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Dim canvas = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
        xpos = Cursor.Position.X - canvas.Location.X
        ypos = Cursor.Position.Y - canvas.Location.Y
    End Sub
```

Note how the *sender* argument gives you a reference back to the picture box object that's being moused.  Do the same thing in any other event handlers.

Comment: ok i got them listed. how do i reference them? i need to be able to change their names after they are created, change their size, delete them, etc.
i have done Dim canvas = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox) in the events then i did for instance, canvases.remove(canvas) but everytime it throws back this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the counter whenever a new canvas is created:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Dim counter As New Integer
    ...

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        counter += 1
        canvas.Name = "canvas" & counter.ToString()
        ...
```

Accessing the canvas that the mouse is currently moving over:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            pos = MousePosition
            pos.X = pos.X - xpos
            pos.Y = pos.Y - ypos
            DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Location = pos
        End If
    End Sub
```